# Consume a SOAP WebService, with WSDL - Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have followed several tutorials to be able to consume a SOAP webservice (wsdl external link). I can't make the connection.

This is my **ClientConfiguration.java**:

```
@Configuration
public class ClientConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage> specified in
        // pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.springsoap.client.gen");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public Client client(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://xxxxxxxxxx.xx/WSService.svc");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);
        return client;
    }
}
```

For example, if this is the link to the wsdl file: **https://xxxxxxxxxx.xx/WSService.svc?wsdl**

What should I put in **client.setDefaultUrl**? **https://xxxxxxxxxx.xx/WSService.svc?wsdl** or **https://xxxxxxxxxx.xx/WSService.svc** (my file is on an external server)

My second question is about my **Client.java**:

```
public class Client extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public GetCodeOmschrijvingResponse getCodes(String tabelName) {

        GetCodeRequest request = new GetCodeRequest();
        JAXBElement<String> element = new JAXBElement<>(new QName("http://tempuri.org/", "tabel"), String.class, tabelName);
        request.setTabel(element);

        GetCodegResponse response = (GetCodeOmschrijvingResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive(" ?????? ", request,
                        new SoapActionCallback(" ?????? "));

        return response;
    }
}
```

I am not sure what parameters or link I should add in the marshalSendAndReceive call.

**UPDATE**

**SpringbootSoapClientApplication.java**

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringbootSoapClientApplication {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringbootSoapClientApplication.class, args);
}

@Bean
CommandLineRunner lookup(Client quoteClient) {
    return args -> {
        String tabelName = "land";

        GetCodeResponse response = quoteClient.getCodes(tabelName);
        System.err.println(response.getGetCodeResult());
    };
}
```

}

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot.soapclient</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-soap-client</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-soap-client</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tag::dependency[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- end::dependency[] -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <!-- tag::wsdl[] -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.14.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>com.springsoap.client.gen</generatePackage>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>https://xxxxxxxxxx.xx/WSService.svc?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- end::wsdl[] -->
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
2020-08-11 12:59:12.836[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m5372[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'marshaller' defined in class path resource [com/springboot/soapclient/ClientConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:226) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551) ~[spring-context-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) ~[spring-boot-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at com.springboot.soapclient.SpringbootSoapClientApplication.main(SpringbootSoapClientApplication.java:14) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.oxm.UncategorizedMappingException: Unknown JAXB exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.convertJaxbException(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:955) ~[spring-oxm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:514) ~[spring-oxm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.afterPropertiesSet(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:480) ~[spring-oxm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1853) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1790) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath.
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:131) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:318) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:478) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:435) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.createJaxbContextFromContextPath(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:537) ~[spring-oxm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller.getJaxbContext(Jaxb2Marshaller.java:500) ~[spring-oxm-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.bind.v2.ContextFactory
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.nullSafeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:92) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at javax.xml.bind.ServiceLoaderUtil.safeLoadClass(ServiceLoaderUtil.java:125) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:128) ~[jakarta.xml.bind-api-2.3.3.jar:2.3.3]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Any idea to help me please?
Thanks! :)

Comment: https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/2132 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093963/java-class-using-jaxb-api-failing-in-jira-with-provider-com-sun-xml-bind-v2-co

Comment: What do you mean? these links can not help me with my problem. Did you check my code and my error?